# Python FastAPI: Returned gif image is not animating

Tags: javascript, python, html, fastapi

Below is my Python FastAPI route and HTML page:

**Python:**

```
@app.get('/', status_code=200)
async def upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
     error_img = Image.open('templates/crying.gif')
     byte_io = BytesIO()
     error_img.save(byte_io, 'png')
     byte_io.seek(0)
     return StreamingResponse(byte_io, media_type='image/gif')
```

**HTML:**

```
<img src="" id="img-maze" alt="this is photo" style="display: none;" />

function goBuster(file) {

    fetch('/', {
        method: 'GET',
        body: data
    })
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(image => {
            var outside = URL.createObjectURL(image);
            var mazeimg = document.getElementById("img-maze");
            mazeimg.onload = () => {
                URL.revokeObjectURL(mazeimg.src);
            }
            mazeimg.setAttribute('src', outside);
            mazeimg.setAttribute('style', 'display:inline-block');

        })
}
```

The image is not animating, I checked the generated HTML and found:

```
<img src="blob:http://127.0.0.1:8000/ee2bda53-92ac-466f-afa5-e6e34fa3d341" id="img-maze" alt="this is  photo" style="display:inline-block">
```

So the image's `src` attribute is using blob, I guess this is the reason why the gif is not animating, but I have no idea how to fix it.

### Update 1

Now I have updated my code to:

```
      with open('templates/crying.gif', 'rb') as f:
        img_raw = f.read()
        byte_io = BytesIO()
        byte_io.write(img_raw)
        byte_io.seek(0)
        return StreamingResponse(byte_io, media_type='image/gif')
```

The generated HTML looks same:

```
<img src="blob:http://127.0.0.1:8000/c3ad0683-3971-4444-bf20-2c9cd5eedc3d" id="img-maze" alt="this is maze photo" style="display:inline-block">
```

but it gets worse, the image is not even showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author, in order to post it in the answer space)*.

I fixed the problem by:

1. using the code provided by @VadSim,
2. change `wb` to `rb`

Notice: if you ran the program and then changed `wb` to `rb`, the code would have destroyed the original gif image to be a 0 bytes image. This is why it was not working at first.

Now, I have the gif working in html :)

Answer (score 1):

```py
error_img.save(byte_io, 'png')
```

You're converting this image to png. PNG doesn't support animation.
I think you can use:

```py
@app.get('/', status_code=200)
async def upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
     with open('templates/crying.gif', 'rb') as f:
         img_raw = f.read()
     byte_io = BytesIO(img_raw)
     return StreamingResponse(byte_io, media_type='image/gif')
```

Comment: Hi Vad, thanks for your answer. It throws an error: `    img_raw = f.read()
io.UnsupportedOperation: read`

Comment: I found the reason, change `wb` to `rb` solved the UnsupportedOperation read`. However, the issue is still there and gets worse, the image does now show up any more.

Comment: hi @vadsim, I will set your post as the answer, could you please update `wb` to `rb`? thanks :)