# How to send animated GIF from memory to FastAPI endpoint?

Tags: python, flask, python-imaging-library, fastapi, animated-gif

I'm trying to send a GIF from memory to my FastAPI endpoint, which works, but the gif isn't animated. When I save it locally instead the animation works fine.
I don't want to save the image, but instead keep it in memory until it's returned to the endpoint.

I've already checked out this post, but still couldn't get it working: [Python FastAPI: Returned gif image is not animating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67571477/python-fastapi-returned-gif-image-is-not-animating)

So how can I return an animated .gif using FastAPI?

This is my attempted solution:

```py
# main.py

@app.get('/youtube/{video_id}.gif')
def youtube_thumbnail (video_id: str, width: int = 320, height: int = 180):
    image = util.create_youtube_gif_thumbnail(video_id)
    return util.gif_to_streaming_response(image)
```

```py
# util.py

def gif_to_streaming_response(image: Image):
    imgio = BytesIO()
    image.save(imgio, 'GIF')
    imgio.seek(0)
    return StreamingResponse(content=imgio, media_type="image/gif")


def create_gif(images, duration):
    gif = images[0]
    output = BytesIO() # for some reason this doesn't work (it shows a still image), but if I save the image with output = "./file.gif" the animation works!
    # this works
    output = "./file.gif"
    gif.save(output, format='GIF', save_all=True, append_images=images, loop=0, duration=duration)
    return gif


def create_youtube_gif_thumbnail(video_id: str):
    images = [read_img_from_url(f"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{video_id}/{i}.jpg") for i in range(1,3)]
    return create_gif(images, 150)
```

Here's the full codebase: https://github.com/Snailedlt/Markdown-Videos/blob/418de75e200bf9d9f4f02e5a667af4c9b226b5d3/util.py#L74

Comment: Did you try outputting the data from `gif.save` to a file to verify that the format is correct? i.e. is there an animated gif present if  you just save it to disk instead of attempting to return it? (attempt to exclude possible reasons, one step at a time)

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes, I've done both `gif.save` in the `create_gif` method and `image.save` in the `gif_to_streaming_response` method. Both worked fine, and outputted an animated GIF file.

Comment: Request the file and save it to disk, compare the two files - i.e. what's the difference between the one saved directly to the disk and the other one that has been served through the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is very difficult to follow, but it looks like you're saving something different to what you're returning from your endpoint.

If I flatten most of your code into a single method it's clearer what's going on:

```
@app.get('/youtube/{video_id}.gif')
def youtube_thumbnail (video_id: str, width: int = 320, height: int = 180):
    # from util.create_youtube_gif_thumbnail(video_id)
    images = [read_img_from_url(f"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{video_id}/{i}.jpg") for i in range(1,3)]
    # from create_gif(images, 150)
    image = images[0]
    image.save("./file.gif", format='GIF', save_all=True, append_images=images, loop=0, duration=150)
    # from util.gif_to_streaming_response(image)
    imgio = BytesIO()
    image.save(imgio, 'GIF')
    imgio.seek(0)
    return StreamingResponse(content=imgio, media_type="image/gif")
```

So you're passing `save_all` and `append_images` when writing to `file.gif`, but not as part of the `StreamingResponse`.

I.e., it's effectively doing:

```
@app.get('/youtube/{video_id}.gif')
def youtube_thumbnail (video_id: str):
    images = [read_img_from_url(f"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{video_id}/{i}.jpg") for i in range(1,3)]
    image = images[0]
    imgio = BytesIO()
    image.save(imgio, 'GIF')
    imgio.seek(0)
    return StreamingResponse(content=imgio, media_type="image/gif")
```

While, I'd suggest doing:

```
@app.get('/youtube/{video_id}.gif')
def youtube_thumbnail (video_id: str):
    first, *following = (
        read_img_from_url(f"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{video_id}/{i+1}.jpg")
        for i in range(3)
    )
    buf = BytesIO()
    first.save(buf, format='GIF', save_all=True, append_images=following, loop=0, duration=150)
    return Response(buf.getvalue(), media_type="image/gif")
```

Note that I've split the frames up into `first` and `following` so that the first doesn't have its duration doubled (as you were implicitly including it twice).  Next, your `range(1,3)` only iterates over `[1, 2]` rather than `[1, 2, 3]` which seem to be the valid range for the videos I tried.  Finally, there is little value in using a `StreamingResponse` as the whole response is already in memory (due to the use of `BytesIO`) hence just passing the `bytearray` directly to a `Response` seems acceptable.

I'd also suggest modifying `read_img_from_url` to check for errors, something like:

```
def read_img_from_url(url: str) -> Image.Image:
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()
    return Image.open(BytesIO(res.content))
```

It's annoying that requests doesn't raise errors like this automatically.   You likely need a `try`/`catch` block anyway as resolver/socket exceptions might be raised internally.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I will try your suggestion this weekend and let you know how it goes, but just from looking at it, it seems like it should work, and it's much cleaner than my code for sure!

Comment: It works perfectly, and it made the code much cleaner, so thank you very much!